# In Eclipse, text link for pop-up in a dynamic layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

In android, how do I create a click-able text link (embedded in a dynamic layout) that produces a pop-up window. I want to put text in the pop-up window.

Is it like creating a hyperlink?

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
String linkText = "<a href='https://www.google.com'>linked text</a>";
link.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkText));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html).
Usage:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("your text");
spannableString.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // show your pop-up here
    }
}, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(spannableString);
```

---